# How to solve the errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" even though my constraint is correct?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I am trying to create three tables :

1. Hotel Table

```
    CREATE TABLE Hotels(
    HotelID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    City VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Rating VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (HotelID)
    
    )
```

2. Rooms table

```
    CREATE TABLE Rooms (
    HotelID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Room_Number INT NOT NULL,
    Price_Rate INT NOT NULL,
    Type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(HotelID, Room_Number),
    FOREIGN KEY(HotelID) REFERENCES hotels(HotelID)
    )
```

3. BookingInfo Table

```
    CREATE TABLE BookingInfo (
    HotelID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    UserID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Room_Number INT NOT NULL,
    Arrival_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Departure_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(UserID, HotelID, Room_Number, Arrival_Date),
    FOREIGN KEY(HotelID) REFERENCES hotels(HotelID),
    FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES users(UserID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Room_Number) REFERENCES rooms(Room_Number)
    )
```

But when I try to create the third table I am getting errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed".

Moreover, when I delete `FOREIGN KEY (Room_Number) REFERENCES rooms(Room_Number)` the table gets created successfully. But I don't understand why it is not accepting `FOREIGN KEY (Room_Number) REFERENCES rooms(Room_Number)`.

I have also tried to alter the table and change data type but still didn't get any success. Can anyone please point out my the mistake in this codes.

Comment: MySQL is case insensitive. And I was automatically being recommended "rooms". Moreover I have used lower case letters for ' FOREIGN KEY(HotelID) REFERENCES hotels(HotelID),
   FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES users(UserID),'

Comment: *MySQL is case insensitive.* Incorrect. Depends on `lower_case_table_names` setting. *point out my the mistake in this codes* Swap columns in `Rooms` primary key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary key of `Rooms` is two columns: `(HotelID, Room_Number)`.

The foreign key in `BookingInfo` is one column: `(Room_Number)`.

A foreign key should reference the *whole* primary key of the referenced table. If that primary key has more than one column, all of the columns must be referenced by the foreign key, and in the same order.

---

Caveat that is not standard SQL and specific to InnoDB: InnoDB allows a foreign key to reference part of a multi-column key in the referenced table, as long as the column is the *leftmost* column of that key. But in your case, you are referencing the second from the left column of that key, `Room_Number`. So it's not allowed. And in my opinion, it's a bad idea anyway to reference part of the key, because it leads to weird data anomalies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I am reading [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-restrictions) but haven't found the restriction as you described in the answer , could you please provide the reference ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-restrictions: _"... in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are the first columns in the same order."_

Comment: OK thanks,  the order of columns in both referencing key and referenced key should also be consistent

Answer (score 1):

REFERENCES rooms(Room_Number) room_number has to be a key or the first node of a multi column key

'In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the guidance. This code has worked for  me :

```
CREATE TABLE BookingInfo (
    HotelID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    UserID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Room_Number INT NOT NULL,
    Arrival_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Departure_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(UserID, HotelID, Room_Number, Arrival_Date),
    FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES users(UserID),
    FOREIGN KEY(HotelID,Room_Number) REFERENCES rooms(HotelID,Room_Number)
    
    )
```